# Navigation with CommandButton not responding

Tags: jsf, navigation, commandbutton

my left menu page (`commonMenu.xhtml`) with `commandButton`:

```
<body>
<h:form>
    <ui:composition>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/project/pages/foo.xhtml">foo</a>  </li>
            <li><p:commandButton value="foo"
                    action="pages/foo" /></li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </ui:composition>
</h:form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

directory tree look like:

```
webapp
----->pages
---------->foo.xhtml
---------->templates
---------------->commonMenu.xhtml
```

Problem:
`href` is working perfectly, however commandButton is not working at all. What can be a reason?

i tried diffrent strings in `action`: `foo`, `project/pages/foo`, `pages/foo` etc...

Comment: I tested on my project, it worked. I don't know what happened with yours. Context root of your project is 'project' ? is there error when load that page?

Comment: Look at the generated code, seems that the `<form>` is not being rendered, thus the `UICommand` won't work.

Comment: @LostHeaven0809 there is no error in log, ye root of my project is 'project'

Answer (score 0):

i read somewhere that for simple navigation i need to use `<p:button>` not `<p:commandButton>`

and i used that with short pathes like just `foo` and it works

so simply i change `commandButton` part for:

```
<p:button value="foo" outcome="foo" />
```

anyway ty